# How to filter only first row of dataview

Tags: asp.net

I have a dataview object in asp.net 3.5, and I need to put a filter on it in such way that I only keep the first row on the dataview.  I've searched for ways to do this, but so far no luck.  The .RowFilter property only seems to work with WHERE criteria, and that is not what I am looking for.  I just need to eliminate all rows except the first one.

Comment: Is the DataView getting data from a DataTable?

Comment: Yes, it is.
dv.table = sourceTable
dv.filter = "some filter here"

where dv is my dataview.  The problem is that I am being passed the dataview into my code, and sometimes the filter is blank.  In the case when the filter is blank, I need to somehow re-filter the dataview in such way that I can return it with only the first row.

Comment: You could delete all rows from data table except the first one? I dont know if your using them or not.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments I can see you have this statement

```
dv.table = sourceTable;
```

just do this to get the first row

```
dv.Table = (new DataRow[] { sourceTable.AsEnumerable().ElementAt(0) }).CopyToDataTable();
```